# How to use many custom validators in same field

Tags: php, yii2

In the same field I have two possible types of data: `CPF` and `CNPJ`. I'm using a [custom component](https://github.com/yiibr/yii2-br-validator) for validations individually, like:

```
['cnpj', CnpjValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true]
```

or

```
['cpf', CpfValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true]
```

but I tried using the two classes for the same field `cnpj_cpf` and it didn't succeeded. The rules will be applied individually based on the `natureza` attribute that belongs to the same model.

something like:

```
if($model->natureza == 'F'){
// apply CpfValidator::className()
else {
// apply CnpjValidator::className()
}
```

@edit

Rules method

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['nome', 'nome_abrev', 'email', 'cliente_grupo_id'], 'required'],
            [['email', 'email_nfe'], 'email'],
            ['cnpj_cpf', CnpjValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true, 'when' => function($model){
                return $model->natureza == 'J';
            }],
            ['cnpj_cpf', CpfValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true, 'when' => function($model){
                return $model->natureza == 'F';
            }],
            [['natureza', 'observacoes'], 'string'],
            [['ativo', 'gera_gnre', 'simples_nacional', 'sintegra', 'emitir_laudo', 'controla_pallet', 'controla_edi', 'regime_especial', 'gera_st', 'termos_industrializacao', 'termo_isencao', 'cod_suframa', 'insc_subs_tributaria', 'ean', 'cliente_grupo_id', 'cliente_ramo_atividade_id', 'localizacao_microrregiao_id', 'venda_canal_id', 'venda_condicao_pagamento_id', 'usuario_representante_id'], 'integer'],
            [['data_suframa','limite_credito_validade','data_insc_subs_tributaria'], 'default', 'value' => null],
            [['data_suframa', 'data_insc_subs_tributaria', 'limite_credito_validade'], 'safe'],
            [['limite_credito', 'desconto_financeiro'], 'number'],
            [['nome', 'nome_abrev', 'insc_estadual', 'insc_municipal', 'email', 'email_nfe', 'website', 'banco', 'banco_ag', 'banco_cc', 'natureza_operacao'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['cnpj_cpf'], 'string', 'max' => 18],
            [['website'], 'url',  'defaultScheme' => 'http'],
            [['nome_abrev'], 'unique'],
            [['venda_canal_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => VendaCanal::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['venda_canal_id' => 'id']],
            [['venda_condicao_pagamento_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => VendaCondicaoPagamento::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['venda_condicao_pagamento_id' => 'id']],
            [['cliente_grupo_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => ClienteGrupo::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['cliente_grupo_id' => 'id']],
            [['localizacao_microrregiao_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => LocalizacaoMicrorregiao::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['localizacao_microrregiao_id' => 'id']],
            [['cliente_ramo_atividade_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => ClienteRamoAtividade::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['cliente_ramo_atividade_id' => 'id']],
            [['usuario_representante_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => UsuarioRepresentante::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['usuario_representante_id' => 'id']]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `[['cnpj_cpf'], 'string', 'max' => 18]` ???

Comment: i removed that line, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```
['cnpj_cpf', CnpjValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true, 'when' => function($model){
    return $model->natureza != 'F';
}],
['cnpj_cpf', CpfValidator::className(), 'skipOnError' => true, 'when' => function($model){
    return $model->natureza == 'F';
}],
```

Read more about [Conditional Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation).

Comment: I try your solution but always get a invalid message even with the correct value. Individually works fine. As if the conditional was not obeyed...

Comment: Yes, added the `whenClient` option. In a update form, the rule getting only value for model and doens't works when change the attribute `natureza`

Comment: Edit your question to add your current validation rules since I can't guess what is wrong...

Comment: Done! Added the rules method